# How to avoid sorting of Dictonary keys in Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am sending an ajax call to get data from server side.

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'data':["100","102","101"] ,
            "compare_data": 0,
            "category": category_val,
            "type": type
        },
        url: "{% url 'test:test_search'  %}",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#loader-div").show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data,"data")
            }
      });
```

from the server side I am returning JsonReponse. Attaching sample here

Response:

```
 response={"100":"test","102":"test12","101":"test13"}
 return JsonResponse({'status':'200','response':response})
```

But when I see the response dictonary in javascript it is changing as

{"100":"test","101":"test13","102":"test12"}

The response is getting sorted. Is there a way to stop sorting of keys ?
I tried changing the type of key to string, even the values are getting sorted.

Comment: If you rely on order, then don't use an object. Use an array or otherwise maintain what the order should be.

Comment: You could use List of tuples if you want it ordered `[("100", "test"), ("102", "test12"), ("101", "test13")]` or you could build an OrderedDict.

Comment: Python dicts, since Python 3.something, maintain the order of key-creation when you iterate through a dict. But in general, dicts or hashes don't have a defined order.

Comment: @erny Python dicts have maintained the order of key-creation since ... quick Google ... Python 3.6 and guaranteed so in 3.7 see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: @nigel222: Thanks. I was aware of this fact, and just tried to verify what exactly django would return, and it doesn't seem to change the order of the dict (in this case it would be: `b'{"status": "200", "response": {"100": "test", "102": "test12", "101": "test13"}}'`). It may be that the browsers console sorts the output by key. The best thing would be to check the service response in the network tab, but I was not the person who asked.

Comment: @nigel222 Python maintaining the order doesn't mean anything, though. That object gets serialised, passed through who-knows-what (there could be a gateway that intercepts data, analyses it and re-serialises. Dealt with this in the past), then gets de-serialised in JS. Each of this can disturb the order as there is *no guarantee* that order would be maintained through the whole route after it leaves in serialised form. JS in particular [has well-defined order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219) for keys since ES6 and that places non-negative integer keys first and in ascending order.

Comment: This isn't a "use the correct Python structure" problem. This is problem with passing around serialised data. See [order of python dict changes when send as a json response (python 3.11.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77439273) where I posted more details about why data sent as JSON is not at all required to maintain the order of the keys. Different parsers *might*. But that's not something to be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

Just return an array of objects from the back end. something like this:

```
[{key: '100', value: 'test'}, {key: '101', value: 'test13'}, /* and so on ... */]
```